# Issue with setting the content type for http request header with axis2

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, content-type, webservice-client

I have a  webservice  client code which accesses a service (Axis2  based). I tried changing the content type in the request header using the following code.

```
ServiceClient serviceClient = stub._getServiceClient();
Options options = serviceClient.getOptions();
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "true");
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.ENABLE_HTTP_CONTENT_NEGOTIATION,"true");
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.MESSAGE_TYPE,"text/xml");
```

But the above code was not working for the content type `text/xml` .But It worked when I used the content type `application/xml` .I was not able to set the content type as `text/xml`.

Can anybody give me a solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need to set the content type? In what way does it fail when you set the type to text/xml?

Comment: Actually the content type, the client expecting is text/xml.But the content type going with my request is application/soap+xml .I was able to change that to application/xml with the code mentioned in my question.But I couldn't change it to text/xml.Even if I am trying to set the type as text/xml , it is not getting changed in the request, and the value application/soap+xml will be there as the content type.@Kenster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client may be using the wrong SOAP version to format its request. `text/xml` is the SOAP 1.1 content type. `application/soap+xml` is the content type for SOAP 1.2.

[This page](http://www.keith-chapman.org/2009/02/axis2-how-to-set-soap-version-on-client.html) illustrates how to change the SOAP version.

```
serviceClient.getOptions().setSoapVersionURI(
              org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAP11Constants.SOAP_ENVELOPE_NAMESPACE_URI);
```

will set the SOAP version to 1.1, for example.